# How to standardize table row height behavior

Tags: html, css, html-table

The code below shows a table with a "rowspan" option at the first cell.

Depending on the browser used (ie, firefox and chrome), the ratio of the height of the detail lines differ.

My question: Is there any way to standardize this behavior, whatever it is?

Thanks for the tip.

```
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">GroupCell<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></td>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">Detail 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Detail 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Detail 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: using a [css reset script](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) may help

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding a fixed height to the `td` will help to standardize the heights across browsers.

CSS:

```
td {
     height:50px;
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BP2At/2/).

Comment: With Chrome it works fine and the behavior can be controled, but IE and Firefox show the rows with the same height, even height option is set or not.